# learn python the hard way exercise explaination: 43

Tags: python

I came across this to-do exercise, but unable to understand some of the code.

Firstly, I am confused with the flow control. I attached a screen-shot having split screen of the same.In second screen it has object declaration and calling the methods.The screenshot has also the compiled output which I highlighted.

Here is part of the code.

```
class Engine(object):
    print 'Inside Engine class'
    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map
        print 'scene_map is:',self.scene_map
    def play(self):
        print "inside play ",self
        flag = True
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        if current_scene =="finish":
            flag = False
        while flag:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            if next_scene_name == "finish":
                exit(0)
            else:
                current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)`

class Map(object):
    print "inside map class"
    scenes = {
            'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
            'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
            'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
            'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
            'death': Death(),
            'finish':Finish()
            }
    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        print start_scene
        self.start_scene = start_scene
    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    def opening_scene(self):
        print "inside opening scene"
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)`
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

output:

```
Inside engine class
inside map class
Central_corridor
scene_map is: <__main__.Map object at 0x00000000029B7908>
inside play  <__main__.Engine object at 0x00000000029B7940>
```

1.Firstly, `Map()` class is called with `central_corridor` as parameter. As per that line It should print `Inside the Map class`.But why am I getting the `Inside Engine class`
2.what is `scene_map`? An object or a reference to the object ??
Thanks.

Comment: Do not put your code or the error message as an image but as text.

Comment: @eyllanesc - you're correct, but no need to undo my edit to embed the image. Nobody should have to click on a link. It's hard enough to understand this question...

Comment: @DavidMakogon If you enable this method you will be supporting the action of placing images as a code or as error messages. I also wanted to enable it to show the image but seeing that it was the error message I did not.

Comment: @eyllanesc   
Thanks for responding. This is my first question ever. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Engine` class is defined on top of the `Map`.

The line printed is written inside the class not inside the contributor. So as long as the class is loaded to the interpreter, the `Inside class` statement will be printed.

Comment: That means the classes are invoked by the interpreter other than objects we created?